# YOURLS Redirect with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, yourls

Currently I am using [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) PHP URL shorterning script.

In their functions.php, seems like they support both redirection which is with PHP header location and javascript.

[Functions.php](http://code.google.com/p/yourls/source/browse/trunk/includes/functions.php?r=251)

I want to redirect with javascript, which will show me the message before redirect. I found this coding inside functions.php

```
// Redirect to another page using Javascript. Set optional (bool)$dontwait to false to force manual redirection (make sure a message has been read by user)
function yourls_redirect_javascript( $location, $dontwait = true ) {
    if( $dontwait ) {
    echo <<<REDIR
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location="$location";
    </script>
    <small>(if you are not redirected after 10 seconds, please <a href="$location">click here</a>)</small>
REDIR;
    } else {
    echo <<<MANUAL
    <p>Please <a href="$location">click here</a></p>
MANUAL;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to do it. Is that coding currently commented or ? What should i change to redirect with javascript ?

Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is all ready to go.  A javascript redirect will occur on the client side, so this script outputs the appropriate javascript.  Call it like so:

```
<?php # http://www.myurl.com/was/here.php

yourls_redirect_javascript('http://www.myurl.com/go/here.php');

?>
```

When this page loads javascript will be used to redirect the user.  If the javascript fails, there will be a link for them to click to follow the redirect.

I suspect that the "here document" syntax is throwing you off a bit.  Read the PHP Docs to learn more about `echo <<<`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php